# Visual Studio 2015 (Update 1) crashes when triggering IntelliSense in cshtml editor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crash, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I open a View file and type something that trigger IntelliSense (<, . or Ctrl + Space), VS immediately crashes without any message and suggest to restart itself.

I opened Event Viewer and see two Error records:

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   application requested process termination through
>   System.Environment.FailFast(string message). Message:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: position at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode.FindToken(Int32
>   position, Boolean findInsideTrivia) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode.FindToken(Int32
>   position, Func`2 findInsideTrivia) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode.FindToken(Int32
>   position, Boolean findInsideTrivia) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode.FindTokenCore(Int32
>   position, Boolean findInsideTrivia) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Extensions.SyntaxTreeExtensions.IsEntirelyWithinStringLiteral(SyntaxTree
>   syntaxTree, Int32 position, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Extensions.SyntaxTreeExtensions.IsInNonUserCode(SyntaxTree
>   syntaxTree, Int32 position, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Completion.Providers.SpeculativeTCompletionProvider.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

The full log file is very long, if you need more, please [see it here](http://pasted.co/3ed7878d).

I ahve tried resetting user data and delete .vs folder in my project but it does not work. Can anyone suggest a fix? Thank you very much.

Comment: I got a similar issue in the past with VS 2012. Uninstalling Extensions and restarting my machine resolved it. I don't know what was the real issue.

Comment: report it on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm

Comment: @triman Damn, I indeed uninstalled some extensions, but did not restart my machine. I am in the middle of repair process though.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, reported.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue after installing language pack for spanish.

Switching back to international settings to English allowed me to continue working on the cshtml. Must mention that if i switch back to spanish, condition reappears:

So go to:
1. Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings.
2. Select English at Language dropdown.

BTW my Visual Studio versión is the Community one, and haven't tried reinstalling the language pack.

Remember seeing a report a while on MS site (cant't find it lately), hope this helps to shed some light on this.